# Gantt chart simulation using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

Is there a way to make the thinner lines in the plot (those without an y axis tick label) appear closer to the lines above (those with a label) so as to better simulate pairs of  baseline / actual bars of the same activity in a gantt chart?
See gantt chart examples [here](http://www.ganttchart.com/Baseli4.png) and [here](http://www.ualr.edu/tswallace/courses/modules/project/images/IMG00028.GIF).

```
mdfr <- structure(list(name = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("100 A", "100 B", 
"101 A", "101 B", "102 A", "102 B", "103 A", "103 B"), class = "factor"), 
    stadio = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 
    1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 
    7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 
    6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("start_date", "end_date"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("05/10/2012", "17/12/2012", "12/03/2012", "30/05/2013", 
    "10/01/2013", "14/10/2013", "24/10/2013", "10/01/2014", "30/09/2013", 
    "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "06/05/2014", "30/09/2013", "29/01/2014", 
    "30/01/2014", "06/05/2014", "05/10/2012", "17/12/2012", "12/03/2012", 
    "30/05/2013", "10/01/2013", "14/10/2013", "24/10/2013", "10/01/2014", 
    "30/09/2013", "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "05/06/2014", "30/09/2013", 
    "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "05/06/2014", "17/12/2012", "12/03/2012", 
    "30/05/2013", "30/05/2014", "14/10/2013", "24/10/2013", "10/01/2014", 
    "11/07/2014", "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "06/05/2014", "23/12/2014", 
    "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "06/05/2014", "23/12/2014", "17/12/2012", 
    "12/03/2012", "30/05/2013", "30/05/2014", "14/10/2013", "24/10/2013", 
    "10/01/2014", "11/07/2014", "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "05/06/2014", 
    "28/12/2014", "29/01/2014", "30/01/2014", "05/06/2014", "29/12/2014"
    ), rating = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("3", 
    "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -64L), .Names = c("name", 
"stage", "variable", "value", "rating"), class = "data.frame")

names <- as.character(unique(mdfr$name))
names1 <- names[gsub("[^ B]","",names) == " B"]
names1 <- paste("No.",gsub("[ B]","",names1),sep="")
names2 <- rep("",length(names1))
new.names <- c(names1,names2)

ggplot(mdfr, aes(as.POSIXct(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y")), name, colour = factor(stage))) +
  geom_line(aes(size=rating)) +
  labs(colour="(Baseline/Actual):", x = "", y = "") +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="RdYlGn",breaks = c("1", "3", "6","8"), guide = "none") +                       
  scale_size_manual(breaks = levels(mdfr$rating),  values = as.integer(levels(mdfr$rating)), guide = "none") +
scale_y_discrete(breaks=names, labels=new.names)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use facets to do this. Below you find a possible solution. This may not be the most elegant solution, but it lets you change the distance between thinner and thicker lines by changing the `expand` argument in `scale_x_discrete`.

```
# numbers to facet by (levels used for order of the facets)
mdfr$nr <- factor(paste0("No.", as.numeric(gsub("A|B", "", mdfr$name))), 
                  levels=unique(paste0("No.", as.numeric(gsub("A|B", "", mdfr$name)))))
# recast your data
df <- dcast(mdfr, nr+stage+rating~variable)
# plot as before, switched x and y values
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(rating),
               ymin=as.POSIXct(as.Date(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")),
               ymax=as.POSIXct(as.Date(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y")), 
               color=factor(stage), 
               size=rating
               )) +
  geom_linerange() + # linerange instead of line
  facet_grid(nr~., scales="free_x") + # faceting
  coord_flip() + # flip coordinates back 
  scale_x_discrete(name="", breaks=NULL, expand=c(4,1)) + # use the expand variable to change the distances 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="RdYlGn",breaks = c("1", "3", "6","8"), guide = "none") +
  scale_size_manual(breaks = levels(mdfr$rating),  values = as.integer(levels(mdfr$rating)), guide = "none")
```

Comment: This is a nice idea! Can the labels be horizontal and appear on the left?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The closest to a reference on this that I could find is the following link: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller